# How gijgo/datepicker to show and select only year/month?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

If there is a way with gijgo/datepicker to show and select only year/month?

I found option format: 'mmmm-yyyy', like

```
$('#expire_date').datepicker({
    uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
    iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    format: 'mmmm-yyyy',
    
    footer: true,
    modal: true, // if to set this parameter to false I have the same problem
    change: function (e) {
        alert('Change is fired : '+e.target.value);
    }
});
```

But it works only partly I need : result is year-month, but day selection is possible...
If, yes, please example...
Thanks!

Comment: Can you specify the version of jQueryUI ?

Comment: I use jQuery 3.5.1 and do not use jQuery-ui.

Comment: Oh, you're using `gijgo` plugin. As I read the [API document](https://gijgo.com/datepicker/configuration), the Datepicker of this plugins does not support this behavior. But you can try jqueryUI which also has DatePicker functions and support the behavior you want

Comment: I have tried  jqueryUI , but it conflicted with tooltips of my fullcalendar and I removed it

Comment: I guess you have to find another library ...